# ListView doesn't show anything

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to windows forms and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  I have a ListView in the front which I created by dragging it from the toolbar named listView1 and modified the View property to be set to "List".  I then try to bind it using the following method:

```
private void BindData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = GetLatestInformation();
    Binding b = new Binding("NAME", dt, "NAME");
    listView1.DataBindings.Add(b);
}
```

Method GetLatestInformation works and table returns with 200 rows of data.  BindData method is reached every single time. Anyone have a clue as to what I am missing?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't need to have `new DataTable()` since the `GetLatestInformation()` call is returning an instance.

Comment: Thanks Davi, I'll keep that in mind.  It doesn't resolve the issue at hand but still good practice when I'm lazy and not initializing variables.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but if i remember correctly, ListView does not support out of the box databinding

Comment: Can anyone confirm or deny what Dark said?  If it doesn't support that, then what purpose does DataBindings.Add(Binding) method do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do is possible, but a quick work around that may be suitable would be to just loop through and add the data manually to the list view...

```
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(dr["NAME"].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: There's got to be a better way, but this definitely does add some data to the screen so I'm giving you a point. Possibly answer mark if nothing better comes up.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from using wpf?  It's much easier to databind to data tables there.  In winforms (from my experience) you usually are manipulating the UI directly.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you need to set the `View` property of the ListView to `Details`?

Comment: No Details seems to give me a blank page as well so I'm avoiding that.  Gosh I never had this problem with dataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that `GetLatestInformation()` is returning a `null` value?

Comment: No, it returns a table that has 200 rows worth of data.